# .NET - Verify and Install .NET Framework 3.5 before running application

Tags: .net, windows-installer, release

PLEASE READ THE FULL QUESTION BEFORE POST YOUR ANSWER

Hello guys!
I'm currently developing a "Extremelly customized Installer Application" in C# for installing a old classic ASP application. It'll be used during the 2.0 version is developed (ASP.NET MVC with C#).

As its so different from the efault install packages, I've made it as normal windows application, not as setup application (a setup application don't let us customize so much as I need).

And here is the problem: As its a windows application, I must "Release" it and send the compiled .EXE with the .DLLs, I must not "Publish" because if i do so, the published .EXE will "install the installer" and not my application. I need a way to verify and install the .NET Framework 3.5 like a bootstrap package prerequisite used in publishing option, but remember that I'm not publishing, I'm doing a "Release" build.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So, what have you tried so far and how has it failed?

Comment: Installer products like WiX, InstallShield, etc, give you everything you need to do this, they are fully customizable. Don't reinvent the wheel. What you are doing is analogous to writing your own database engine because you didn't take the time to learn about sql and stored procs for an existing DBMS.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but the developer that coded this spent about 2 months doing so, and now I have to use it. If I use any installshield-like app, he'll probably be fired, and I don't want this to happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it will help if you stop thinking about it being an installer but consider it a configuration utility.  That needs an installer before it can run.  Just create a regular Setup project for it, one that automatically launches the utility after it is installed.  Check [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/67a106f4-8c95-4216-bd65-f6654b2c2a39) for an example on how to do that.

Comment: you got a point!
as it configures SQL Server, IIS and some folder permissions~in the computer, it can be called as "configuration utility", nice tip

Comment: +1 - i've often done that as a way of avoiding making installers too complex.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably not what you are asking for, however, have you considered using the [WiX toolkit](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

> The Windows Installer XML (WiX) is a
>   toolset that builds Windows
>   installation packages from XML source
>   code. The toolset supports a command
>   line environment that developers may
>   integrate into their build processes
>   to build MSI and MSM setup packages.

The WiX toolkit builds Windows Installer (MSIs) which are geared for installing software, there is very little you can not do with custom actions and there are simple ways of doing custom tasks such as installing prerequisites. By the sounds of it the one you are looking for is ["How To: Install the .NET Framework Using a Bootstrapper"](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm).

I would highly advise using Windows Installer over a custom setup application (EXE), as there are environments that you will not be able to test for, and may not have even considered.

Windows Installer has been extensively tested over the years it has been used, for me personally as a Systems Administrator seeing a MSI download boosts my confidence in the application; in my experience Windows Installer packages are less troublesome than custom install solutions.

Comment: It's funny my reaction is the oposite, I start to wonder 'What the hell are they going to do to my system?' Maybe that is my anal retentive engineer traits taking over.

Comment: I alrealy know everything you wrote, that's not what I've asked for, but thank you for trying helping me

Comment: @kenny, with a little knowledge of the inner workings of a Windows Installer Database you can open up the .MSI in Orca and see exactly what it is doing. You have also got a huge swathe of logging options through MSIEXEC.exe.

Comment: @Tufo, had a feeling you might say that.

Answer (score 0):

[Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is a very [popular](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Users) alternative

[sample code to get .Net framework version](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Get_.NET_Version)

Comment: For .NET 3.5 use: ReadRegDWORD $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" SP

Comment: sorry, we don't have time to expertise this software in time, we have to send the installer dvd tomorrow...

Comment: @Tufo you could batch file it then :)